# fastest way to get data from url

Tags: php, jquery, curl, file-get-contents, getjson

I want to read the data from Linkedin URL, like https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https://stackoverflow.com/&format=json

I have a few methods to do, but I can't find the right/fastest solution.

1. file_get_contents(): takes about 6 seconds
2. using cURL: takes about 3 seconds
3. jquery getJSON: takes less then 1 second

What does this mean? Is the issue with my server? Or do I need to use another function?

--
Extra information:
I've create a test with several domains.

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.linkedin.com");
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time[test1] = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
$data = file_get_contents("https://stackoverflow.com/");
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time[test2] = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com");
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time[test3] = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.expedia.com");
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time[test4] = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.booking.com");
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time[test5] = $time_end - $time_start;

print_r($time);
?>
```

with the following output:

```
    Array
    (
        [test1] => 3.5712170600891
        [test2] => 0.92465400695801
        [test3] => 6.2011067867279
        [test4] => 1.8765568733215
        [test5] => 1.758278131485
    )
```

Comment: getJSON will load data from client side. Rest two are server side

Comment: Take a look at the Requests library: https://github.com/rmccue/Requests

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why there are different durations. The load the linkedin server handling the request, the load of the internet connection, the load of the server or pc. With  only these three numbers no one can tell you if it is a problem at all, and if it is where the problem is.

Comment: @hjpotter92: will it? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Where are your remote server located? is a shared hosting or dedicated machine? There are several factors that can increase time between remote server and linkedin.

Comment: @manuelbcd it's a dedicated machine with very low usage. Located in The Netherlands.

Comment: Where are you located? If your location and dedicated machine are really far away... that could explain why both face different connection times

Comment: @hjpotter92: no, it will not. You can get data from remote URLs with getJSON too.

Comment: @IkoTikashi I never denied that `getJSON` won't fetch the data. I said that it'll use client side connection to achieve it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Okay, to me it sounded like "getJSON is faster because it's clientside" - you'd still need to make a HTTP request to fetch the data.